# Override wallpaper with VMware AirWatch Agent

Tags: vmware, mobile-device-management

I have a corporate MacBook Pro (2015), and it has VMware AirWatch Agent (2.3.3) installed.

I'm fine with that. It is their laptop and I still have Admin rights for my work.

Only thing is... they have locked my Wallpaper with something quite ugly and I can't change it in the normal way. This is literally the only setting I want to get around. Any idea how I could change it without uninstalling the agent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigate to a folder called (0)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298141/navigate-to-a-folder-called-0)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the success rate of overriding MDM enforced configuration changes is very low. Pragmatically:

- You can remove the management profile and then make changes as you see fit.
- You can request your device be moved to a different group under air watch that relaxes that restriction.

There could be a bug you could exploit, but Apple and/or air watch would likely patch that since it would also likely be a noticeable failure.