# Navigate to a folder called (0)

Tags: terminal, finder, bash

VMWare AirWatch (an MDM managemt framework) locks my Desktop background picture ([Override wallpaper with VMware AirWatch Agent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298066/override-wallpaper-with-vmware-airwatch-agent))

I tried to find the existing picture with the following command in Sierra:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock desktop-picture-show-debug-text -bool TRUE;
killall Dock
```

and it showed me that the picture was in `(0)/Library/Wallpaper.jpg`

How can I access this folder with the intent to change this managed setting.

Comment: The defaults command either is intentionally lying to you or the security mechanism to obscure the true location of the file. Clearly (0) is an invalid file path and possibly some sort of variable substitution. My guess is some machine generated temporary folder (like `echo $TMPDIR`) - perhaps restricted by SIP or other protections is in play, but the presumption here might be false that you can simply navigate to a folder to change your desktop file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(0)` is not part of the path. I'm not sure what it is, to be honest

I tried that terminal command and for me it says:

**Screen 1 (space 1):**

`(14)/Users/joonaspaakko/Documents/uDesktop NEXT Library/Catalog/uDNature7658.jpg`

**Screen 2 (space 1):**

`(19)/Users/joonaspaakko/Documents/uDesktop NEXT Library/Catalog/uDNature7658.jpg`

**Screen 1 (space 2):**

`(3)/Users/joonaspaakko/Documents/uDesktop NEXT Library/Catalog/uDNature7408.jpg`

**Screen 2 (space 2):**

`(9)/Users/joonaspaakko/Documents/uDesktop NEXT Library/Catalog/uDNature7408.jpg`

etc....

---

When I navigate to the path ignoring the parenthesis and the number, I get to the folder with the wallpaper, which in my case is: `/Users/joonaspaakko/Documents/uDesktop NEXT Library/Catalog/`

So based on that I would say your wallpaper is in `/Library/`. You can get there easily with the `Go to Folder...`, but in case you are not aware, that is the global `Library` folder you can find, if you go to `Machintosh HD`

Comment: This really isn’t about navigating to a folder since the OP is assuming they can simply change a file to get out of a managed setting. Your answer would work if the OP simply deletes the profile that keeps the Mac under management. However, it’s also overkill. Once MDM is removed, they can set any background they please from system preferences.

Comment: @bmike, I was pretty sure that was what this question was about. What is this question about then?

Comment: See here - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298066/override-wallpaper-with-vmware-airwatch-agent

Comment: @bmike, not to be incredibly pedantic, but that is a different question though. I get your point now, but this question to me is definitely asking how to navigate to this current wallpaper folder, which he believes to be `(0)/Library/` and my answer explains that it's actually `/Library/`. What he intents to do in that folder is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: To be clear - the problem is with the phrasing of the question - not with your attempt to clarify / answer / help. See my comment on the question. Your answer could be summarized as (0) is not a valid path - fix your query to get the correct path or use a tool like `spotlight` or `find` or `locate` and hope that the true location of that file is indexed or searchable.

Comment: @joonas : I'm now also believing that '(0)' is not a valid path, and quite possibly it just isn't possible to navigate there at all. Still I'd be interested to know at least what it is (e.g. encrypted folder)

Comment: @Andrew actually, I thought I demonstrated in my answer that the number + parenthesis is not part of the path at all. I think it's an index number of some kind, not that it matters. Just ignore it and try the `/Library/` path.

Comment: @Joonas - as far as I am aware, your position is what I was agreeing with. However the path definitely does not lead to my User's 'Library' folder, so now I am just curious as to where exactly it is pointing (even if I have no hope of accessing that location).

Comment: @Andrew, I feel like you missed the key points of what I've said so far. In my answer I said  I found out that if I remove the parenthesis and the number from the front, the path leads to the wallpaper, yet you still commented about how you think it's not possible to navigate to `(0)`. Yes, it isn't possible, because it's not part of the path at all. At the bottom of the answer I say the path is `/Library/` and not the user library folder `~/Library/`, as those can be easy to mix. Please try to use the `Go to folder...` command and put in `/Library/` and you should find the wallpaper there.

Comment: Its not necessary for the file to be in the user account library, in fact if the intent of the software was that all users shall have the same desktop image, /Library would be a usable place to put it. It isn't recommended for apps to put things directly in /Library, and the app probably wouldn't pass review for placement in the app store.

Comment: @Joonas - that is now clear. I was confused between ~/Library/ and /Library/ . I was able to navigate right there with the Finder 'Go' command. I was even able to take a new image, rename it it to the old Wallpaper name, replace the old wallpaper file, reset the dock, and now it shows the new Desktop image fine.

Comment: @Andrew good. Glad you got that sorted.

Answer (score 0):

~/Library maybe?
Finder -> Go -> Go to folder...

Comment: Unfortunately not. ~/Library will take me to my current User Library folder. The (0) folder is a mysterious hidden folder that I haven't been able to find any reference to yet...